# Multiple layouts android

Tags: android, xml, layout

Im trying to set up my app with several layouts so that it will change depending on screen resolution. So i have a ldpi,mdpi, hdpi and a xhdpi. Everything seems to work in the sense that it changes, but to my question.

Is there a way to manually set which resolution to use which layout? for example now when i run it on my Galaxy nexus, it uses the hdpi layout and that just looks terrible, i want it to use xhdpi

regards,
Fredkr

Comment: Why won't you put the layout you want to be shown on your device in the right directory?

Comment: As an aside, I'm surprised the Galaxy Nexus is using hdpi. I would have thought that it would be xhdpi as it is [316dpi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density#Samsung) and [xhdpi is ~320dpi](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)

Comment: @kabuko my GNex uses xhdpi for sure (no density modifications), just in case this question turned your world topsy-turvy ;)

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you set up your hdpi layout to look the way you would like it to rather than trying to force another layout? Your app will automatically select the layout it should use based on the screen size and pixel density of your phone.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/screens.html
If this is an app for more than personal use, you will want to fix your hdpi layouts

Comment: well, it does look fine on most cases, the hdpi i set to match the more normal "large" screens out there. its just on my GN it looks like crap

Comment: What exactly looks bad? Images? Layout spacing?

Comment: Do you have different sets of images for each of the different resolution types? Also in your layouts what are you using to set height/width of elements?
Pics could help if you have them

Comment: @Fredkr You can specify different resource directories for devices which have the same density, but different size too, by appending more resource qualifiers to the resource directory names.